# Matlab vs Numpy inner product, different results

Tags: python, numpy, matlab, translation

I'm translating some old Matlab code I was given to python. I'm experiencing some behavior I don't understand and to which I didn't find a proper answer:

I want to multiply two vectors containing complex numbers with an inner product, so I expect to get a complex scalar.
Here is a MWE for Matlab ( I ran it in Octave, so maybe that's an issue?):

```
a = [-0.21+0.58i -0.02-0.23i 0.23-0.39i];
b = [ 1.41-1.63i -0.46+0.69i -1.11+1.08i];
a*b'
ans = -2.06750 + 0.77960i
```

Here the same thing in python:

```
a = np.array([-0.21+0.58j, -0.02-0.23j ,
        0.23-0.39j])
b = np.array([1.41-1.63j, -0.46 +0.69j,
       -1.11+1.08j])
a@b
(0.9830999999999999+1.9333999999999998j)
```

I don't really know much about Matlab but I tried to find as much information about differences to python/numpy as possible and can't find any way to get the same result in python. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here?

Best
Lucas

Comment: `b'` is a conjugate transpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe `b'` in Matlab is `conjugate` in Python, so you want

```
a@b.conj()
# (-2.0675+0.7796000000000001j)
```

which is the correct inner product, while `a@b` is (mathematically) not an inner product.

Comment: `numpy` has something like `vdot` that uses the `conj`

Comment: For clarity, note that the MATLAB dot( ) function (i.e., inner product) puts the conjugate on the 1st argument instead of the 2nd argument. E.g., if you had complex column vectors a and b in MATLAB, then dot(a,b) would be equivalent to a' * b. Other sites (e.g., Wikipedia) put the conjugate on the 2nd argument. So be careful if you are calling pre-canned dot product functions for this operation and make sure you know that the conjugation goes with your desired operand. According to the NumPy doc the vdot( ) function puts the conjugate on the 1st argument also, like MATLAB.

Comment: I will add that the BLAS/LAPACK interface for the complex inner product functions CDOTC( ) and ZDOTC( ) also conjugate the 1st argument, like NumPy vdot( ) and MATLAB dot( ).